# NetUseAdd returns 1326 trying to establish a connection with a remote domain

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, network-programming, smb

I'm trying to use `CreateFile()` to access a remote system. `NetUseAdd()` is used to establish the connection with the remote system so that `CreateFile()` can execute successfully.

I've passed the correct username and password on the domain, but error 1326 (The user name or password is incorrect) is returned.

After examining the network traffic, I noticed it passes the username of the executor, instead of the username of the remote system (the passed username):

> Session Setup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: .\localhost

But here is the passed arguments (and the code, of course):

```cpp
net::Establish(L"\\\\192.168.1.10", L"user", L"password");
```

```cpp
bool net::Establish(const wchar_t* domain, const wchar_t* user, const wchar_t* password) {

    HANDLE remotebin;
    DWORD ret;
    char RemoteBinPath[MAX_PATH];

    // Establish the connection with the remote domain
    USER_INFO_1 userinfo;
    userinfo.usri1_name = (LPWSTR)user;
    userinfo.usri1_password = (LPWSTR)password;
    userinfo.usri1_priv = USER_PRIV_USER;
    userinfo.usri1_home_dir = NULL;
    userinfo.usri1_comment = NULL;
    userinfo.usri1_flags = UF_SCRIPT | UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT;
    userinfo.usri1_script_path = NULL;

    ret = NetUseAdd((LPTSTR)domain, 1, (LPBYTE)&userinfo, MB_OK);
    if (ret != NERR_Success) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Erorr: NetUseAdd: %d\n", ret);
#endif
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask a specific question. For debugging help, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention that you are calling [`NetUseAdd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/nf-lmuse-netuseadd) (**USE**) instead of [`NetUserAdd()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netuseradd) (**USER**). By setting the `LevelFlags` parameter to `1`, you are telling `NetUseAdd()` (**USE**) to expect a pointer to a [`USE_INFO_1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/ns-lmuse-use_info_1) (**USE**) struct, however you are actually passing in a pointer to a [`USER_INFO_1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/ns-lmaccess-user_info_1) (**USER**) struct instead.  The two structs are very different.  Since you are not passing in a proper `USE_INFO_1` (**USE**) struct, you end up with the `ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE` error.

That being said, `NetUseAdd()` (**USE**) at level 1 does not take in a username, only a password.  To pass in a username (and domain), you need to use level 2 ([`USE_INFO_2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmuse/ns-lmuse-use_info_2)) instead. However, to use either level, you will have to also pass in a UNC share path, too.

Try this:

```cpp
net::Establish(L"\\\\192.168.1.10", L"\\\\192.168.1.10\\share", L"domain", L"user", L"password");
```

```cpp
bool net::Establish(const wchar_t* server, const wchar_t* share, const wchar_t* domain, const wchar_t* user, const wchar_t* password) {

    // Establish the connection with the remote domain
    USE_INFO_2 useinfo = {};
    useinfo.ui2_remote = (LPWSTR)share;
    useinfo.ui2_password = (LPWSTR)password;
    useinfo.ui2_asg_type = USE_WILDCARD;
    useinfo.ui2_username = (LPWSTR)user;
    useinfo.ui2_domainname = (LPWSTR)domain;

    DWORD ret = NetUseAdd((LPTSTR)server, 2, (LPBYTE)&useinfo, NULL);
    if (ret != NERR_Success) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Error: NetUseAdd: %d\n", ret);
#endif
        return false;
    }
```

---

On a side note:

The `(LPTSTR)server` type-cast is questionable.  It will work fine if you are compiling with `UNICODE` defined, but it will not work at all if you are not compiling with `UNICODE` defined. Since you are dealing with `wchar_t` strings exclusively, not `TCHAR` strings, you really should just avoid the typecast altogether since `NetUseAdd()` takes only `wchar_t` strings on Windows anyway, not `TCHAR` strings.

Also, when casting your `const wchar_t*` pointers to `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`), you should be using `const_cast` instead of a C-style cast.

Also, use `reinterpret_cast` instead of a C-style cast when passing in the `USE_INFO_...` pointer to `NetUseAdd().

Try this:

```cpp
net::Establish(L"\\\\192.168.1.10", L"\\\\192.168.1.10\\share", L"domain", L"user", L"password");
```

```cpp
bool net::Establish(const wchar_t* server, const wchar_t* share, const wchar_t* domain, const wchar_t* user, const wchar_t* password) {

    // Establish the connection with the remote domain
    USE_INFO_2 useinfo = {};
    useinfo.ui2_remote = const_cast<LPWSTR>(share);
    useinfo.ui2_password = const_cast<LPWSTR>(password);
    useinfo.ui2_asg_type = USE_WILDCARD;
    useinfo.ui2_username = const_cast<LPWSTR>(user);
    useinfo.ui2_domainname = const_cast<LPWSTR>(domain);

    DWORD ret = NetUseAdd(server, 2, reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(&useinfo), NULL);
    if (ret != NERR_Success) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Error: NetUseAdd: %d\n", ret);
#endif
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No `NetUseAdd` is what I'm trying to use. Also I'm confused about how the username should be specified ...
If this function doesn't accept username, then what should I do ?

Comment: Try using `WNetAddConnection2()` instead of `NetUseAdd()`.

Comment: Well it is actually used to redirect the resource to a local device. I don't want to do the mapping, just the authentication for `CreateFile`

Comment: `WNetAddConnection2()` is not required to redirect a local device, same as `NetUseAdd()`. In any case, I jut realized that `NetUseAdd()` *can* take a username, just not at level 1. You need level 2 instead. I have updated my answer